# ReflectionOnly loading is not supported on this platform.F# Compiler(3053) on VSC After Installing RProvider

Tags: f#, f#-data

I installed RProvider 1.1.22 on Visual Studio and it worked with dotnetcore 3.1 and R 3.4.4. I tried to do the same thing using Visual Studio Code, but after installing RProvider I get this error "the type provider 'RProvider.RProvider' reported an error: The type provider constructor has thrown an exception: ReflectionOnly loading is not supported on this platform.F# Compiler(3053)"

Does anyone know what causes this error and its fix? If not, I would appreciate explaining the meaning of "Reflection Only loading". I tried searching it on the web but with no luck.

Update: RProvider worked with me on visual studio even with .Net 5. However, as @CaringDev mentioned, there seems to be a problem with the new dotnet build. It will only build through MSBuild.exe.

Answer (score 0):

<del>[Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyload?view=net-5.0) is not supported on NET 5.0. If you want to use RProvider in VS Code you will have to target netcore3.1.</del>

It seems RProvider does not work with new SDK-style projects. The message containing ReflectionOnly loading is mentioned in a [PR](https://github.com/fslaborg/RProvider/pull/205#issuecomment-735412149)
Given that the RProvider project is not actively maintained, I fear you are on your own.

Comment: I created a new project using netcore3.1, but it still throws the same exception when i installed RProvider.